# Asyncio и многопточность

Tags: python, асинхронность, asyncio, tornado

У меня веб сервер Tornado. Раньше использовал его кроутины и замечал, что работает только 1 поток. То есть от того, что на сервере 8 ядер проку не было. Хотя, надо признать, что на 1 ядре очень хорошие показатели производительности.

Сейчас делаю на Tornado + AsyncIo. И я так понимаю ведь будет также, будет работать только на одном потоке? Есть ли возможность запустить несколько потоков? Есть конечно возможность запустить 2 инстанса сервера, но это тогда разные порты и проблема синхронизации. Память у меня в Redis. Однако такие вещи как активное соеденение с сокетом и общение с ним я не могу хранить в redis разумеется. И придётся еще выяснять какое соеденение на каком инстансе. Хотелось бы, чтобы память всё-таки одна была, а вот производительная мощь задействовала несколько ядер.

Comment: С [12-факторным подходом](https://12factor.net/ru/) никаких проблем.

Comment: А позвольте поинтересоваться, какая вам вообще разница, какое соединение на каком инстансе? В среднестатистическом веб-сервере это обычно вообще ни на что не влияет

Comment: Если у юзера на одном инстансе что-то произойдёт, что потребует оповестить юзера на другом инстансе придётся через redis или другие мб MQ сообщать инстансу который владеет сокетом с юзером которого нужно оповестить. Мне хотелось этого избежать. Конечно же можно чтобы веб сервер держал только сокеты, а куча микросервисов отдельно занимались другими задачами - но это усложняет архитектуру. Может как нибудь я бы этим занялся, но пока хочется сделать на лайте.

Comment: @iproger «на лайте» тогда можно не заморачиваться и жить в одном потоке :) К моменту, когда мощности одного потока станет не хватать, вы неизбежно уже перейдёте на redis или прочие MQ.

Comment: Ну да, это понятно. Просто думал есть простой способ распаралелить, но видимо в питоне с потоками туговато всё.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если сокет-сервер на базе Торнадо, то вот смотри тут https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/tcpserver.html

```
server = TCPServer()
server.bind(8888)
server.start(0)  # Forks multiple sub-processes
IOLoop.current().start()
```

`server.start(0)` вместо listen запустит несколько воркеров по количеству ядер.

Тут TCPServer заменишь на tornado.web.Application. https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/b4e39e52cd27d6b3b324a399dff046f71545c4a5/tornado/web.py#L2115

```
app = make_app()
server = HTTPServer(app)
server.bind(8888)
server.start(0)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

А asyncio в торнадо реализованно заменой loop. Ничего дополнительно не нужно.

Comment: Да, для мультипроцессинга это удобно. Чтобы 1 порт слушало несколько воркеров. Но наверное websocket соеденения у каждого воркера будут хранится отдельно? Или как-то оно под капотом синхронизируется?

Comment: Вэбсокет это соединение будет жить на одном воркере

Comment: 1 порт слушают, дергают socket.accept() по очереди

Comment: зачем синхронизироваться?)

Comment: Понял, тогда круто.